# Change the theme of a standart Theme of telerik

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, telerik, themes

Hi I like the theme :Expression_DarkTheme
But I need to change some behaviour in the RadPanelBar of this theme( Remove some gradiant ....)

Where can I found the source of this theme beacause I need to reproduce the same behaviour just remove the gradiant in the RadPanelItem

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/common-styling-apperance-modifying-built-in-theme.html) from Telerik

Comment: thnks  for your answer I have only the dlls that is why i had a problem , I am downloading the sample from telerik Site